# How do I store a byte into a 4 byte number without changing the bytes around it?

Tags: bit-manipulation

So if I have a 4 byte number (say hex) and want to store a byte say DD into hex, at the nth byte position without changing the other elements of hex's number, what's the easiest way of going about that? I'm guessing it's some combination of bitwise operations, but I'm still quite new with them, and have found them quite confusing thus far?

Answer (score 4):

```
byte n = 0xDD;
uint i = 0x12345678;
i = (i & ~0x0000FF00) | ((uint)n << 8);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, be careful if you're doing this with signed data types, so that things don't get inadvertently sign-extended.

Comment: What do I have to avoid exactly if the data is signed?

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to go wrong given what I've written above, but if `byte` was signed, then saying `i = (i & ~0x0000FF00) | (n << 8)` would actually sign-extend `n` and set all the bits above `n`, so you have to make sure to cast like I did.

Answer (score 1):

Mehrdad's answer shows how to do it with bit manipulation.  You could also use the old byte array trick (assuming C or some other language that allows this silliness):

```
byte n = 0xDD;
uint i = 0x12345678;
byte *b = (byte*)&i;
b[1] = n;
```

Of course, that's processor specific in that big-endian machines have the bytes reversed from little-endian.  Also, this technique limits you to working on exact byte boundaries whereas the bit manipulation will let you modify any given 8 bits.  That is, you might want to turn `0x12345678` into `0x12345DD8`, which the technique I show won't do.